# Programmatically accessing the launch screen XIB or storyboard

Tags: ios, ios8

How can an app access the XIB or storyboard used for its launch screen? The XIB is not in the main bundle (ex: `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathsForResourcesOfType(nil, inDirectory: "")`). This is especially unexpected since "Launch Screen.xib" is listed in the "Copy Bundle Resources" build phase but doesn't show ip in the bundle, so Xcode must be treating it specially.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Xib is not in the main bundle getting path returns nil, But you can get the XIB of the launch screen without the help of path using method

```
  let launchScreenNib = UINib(nibName: "LaunchScreen", bundle: nil)
```

or

You can load get views from XIB as

```
// Swift
let objects = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("LaunchScreen", owner: self, options: nil)
let view = objects[0] as UIView

// Obj C
NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LaunchScreen" owner:self options:nil];
UIView *view = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Xcode wasn't generating the NIB for the launch screen so this code would crash. If the NIB isn't in the bundle then `bundle.loadNibNamed(...)` doesn't work. I was able to get it working by playing with the "Use as Launch Screen" option in Interface Builder which made Xcode generate the NIB.

Comment: @ide update Xcode , by default it creates LaunchScreen.xib during the project creation itself.

Comment: I mean I had LaunchScreen.xib and it was being displayed when I launched the app... just that Xcode was not converting it into a NIB file and copying it to the bundle.

Answer (score 16):

If LaunchScreen is `storyboard` and not a `xib`, Use the following code.

```
let launchScreen = UIStoryboard(name: "LaunchScreen", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
if let launchView = launchScreen?.view {
  view.addSubview(launchView)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up to my own question, it looks like toggling "Use as Launch Screen" off and on caused Xcode to build a NIB file for the launch screen.

1. After doing a complete clean (removed DerivedData) and deleting the app from the device, I toggled off "Use as Launch Screen" for the main view controller in LaunchScreen.xib. Running the app caused it to launch without a launch screen, but the build was now creating LaunchScreen.nib.
2. Did a complete clean again and deleted the app from the device. Toggled "Use as Launch Screen" back on and rebuilt. In the app bundle under the new DerivedData folder, LaunchScreen.nib was still there.
3. `bundle.loadNibNamed(...)` worked fine now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a Swift 5, SceneDelegate implementation**

This implementation also detects the LaunchScreen's configured name from the `info.plist` file.

```
//
//  SceneDelegate.swift
//  Extended Launch Screen Example
//
//  Created by Leslie Godwin on 2020/04/24.
//

import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate
{
    var window:       UIWindow?
    var splashWindow: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)
    {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene)
    {
        // Called as the scene is being released by the system.
        // This occurs shortly after the scene enters the background, or when its session is discarded.
        // Release any resources associated with this scene that can be re-created the next time the scene connects.
        // The scene may re-connect later, as its session was not neccessarily discarded (see `application:didDiscardSceneSessions` instead).
    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene)
    {
        // ⏳Extend Splash screen only if `splashWindow` is `nil` otherwise it is already shown.
        //
        if let launchStoryboardName = InfoPList.launchStoryboardName,
           let windowScene          = self.window?.windowScene
        {
            splashWindow = splashWindow ??
            {
                let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
                    window.windowLevel = .statusBar

                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: launchStoryboardName, bundle: nil)

                window.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
                window.isHidden           = false

                // ⏳Wait for 5 seconds, then remove.
                //
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(5))
                {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: -1, // system default
                        animations:
                        {
                            self.splashWindow?.alpha = 0
                        },
                        completion:
                        { _ in
                            self.splashWindow?.isHidden = true
                            self.splashWindow = nil
                        }
                    )
                }

                return window
            }()
        }

        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene will move from an active state to an inactive state.
        // This may occur due to temporary interruptions (ex. an incoming phone call).
    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the background to the foreground.
        // Use this method to undo the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called as the scene transitions from the foreground to the background.
        // Use this method to save data, release shared resources, and store enough scene-specific state information
        // to restore the scene back to its current state.
    }
}

//
// PList Helper
//

struct InfoPList
{
    private static func value(for name: String) -> String? { Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: name) as? String }

    static var bundleIdentifier:         String? { self.value(for: "CFBundleIdentifier") }
    static var bundleDisplayName:        String? { self.value(for: "CFBundleDisplayName") }
    static var bundleShortVersionString: String? { self.value(for: "CFBundleShortVersionString") }
    static var bundleVersion:            String? { self.value(for: "CFBundleVersion") }

    static var launchStoryboardName: String? { self.value(for: "UILaunchStoryboardName") }
    static var mainStoryboardName:   String? { self.value(for: "UIMainStoryboardFile") }
}
```